# moving the button to the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I need to align these buttons at the end of this section, these would be inside of a horizontal alignment with 3 other boxes as shown on the picture

[image: show the way it looks now]

I'm sure it's a pretty easy issue to solve but I can't get my mind around how to do it

```css
div.button1 {
  align-items: baseline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.level {
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.levelbox {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.185);
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.leveltext {
  height: 261.44px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- levele 2 -->
<div class="levelbox" id="box2">
  <div id="img"><img src="img/arnol.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="leveltext" id="text">
    <h3>Para Intermedios</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Si ya tienes experiencia, tu nivel físico o capacidad para entrenar es de un nivel intermedio y quieres aumentar tu masa muscular, ¡este entrenamiento es para ti!</p>
    <br>
    <div class="button1">
      <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="button"><span>Empieza</span></button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS?

Comment: there you have it

Comment: since you already using `height` for the boxes, you can make them `position: relative`, and the buttons be `position: absolute` to the `bottom: 10px`

Comment: `position absolute` might cause a responsive disaster, always try to refrain from using it unless there's really no other alternative. It's better to use `margin-top: auto` like Cédric suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `margin-top:auto;`. Here I use a flex container so the contents have the same height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#blue,#grey,#red,.button {
  width: 100%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

#grey {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 75px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="grey"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```