# Is it possible with css to bring a "nested" <div> to the bottom of antoher div

Tags: html, css

in mean this:

HTML looks like this...

```
<div id="div1">
something...

**<div id="div2">
</div**>
</div>
```

`<div id="div2">` should always be positioned at the bottom
of `<div id="div1">`

Comment: you put position relative to div1. position absolute div2 with bottom to 0

Comment: Using `margin-top:auto` : [moving the button to the bottom of the div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011766/17684809)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to using position : reletive and absolute.

You can move div any side..
And also use flex to and flex properti **order**. Example order:2.

Bellow code work after applying display flex.

Comment: It would be nice to share some real example code which you should test before posting. That way you would find and avoid spelling errors like "reletive" (correctly: relative).